# How to sync git branch with remote branch?

Tags: git, github

There is a project on GitHub with 2 branches:

```
project/Master
project/stable-v1
```

I forked the project so now in my private github account I have:

```
myGitHub/Master
myGitHub/stable-v1
```

I downloaded the project to my local mac using SSH so now in my mac I have:

```
local/Master
local/stable-v1
```

Now, since `local/stable-v1` & `myGitHub/stable-v1` are 290 commits behind `project/stable-v1` I want to get all these commits.

All guides I found talk about rebase onto Master. This is not what is needed here.
the two branches are very different and should be never merged. They run in parallel.

How can I do such rebase?
I tried to navigate `local/stable-v1` and just do:

```
git pull
```

but for some reason it gave me so many conflicts (not sure why? I don't have any changes locally)

I tried

```
git pull --rebase origin stable-v1
```

but that also created so many conflicts.

How can I just say ignore everything just make local/stable-v1 exactly the same as project/stable-v1 and push this also to myGitHub/stable-v1 without changing anything on Master branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the upstream repository as a remote to your clone (when cloning, you automatically get the `origin` remote:

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com/project/repo.git
```

Then you can fetch from this remote and perform any operation you like, e.g.:

```
git checkout stable-v1
git fetch upstream
git merge --ff-only upstream/stable-v1
git push origin stable-v1
```

Comment: why upstream/master ?

Comment: @sony `upstream` is the name of your remote and `master` is the name of the remote branch. `upstream/master` is the name of the remote-tracking branch. It follows the same schema as `origin/master`

Comment: but I don't want to reabse master branch, i want to rebase only stable-v1 branch from project/stable-v1

Comment: Then `upstream/stable-v1`

Comment: Just to be clear project/stable-v1 is upstream and myGitHub/stable-v1 is origin?

Comment: If you have set up your remotes that way, then yes. When cloning, the default remote will always be `origin`. Any other remote that you add gets the name that you specify when adding it.