# rebase branch from remote

Tags: git, pycharm

There is a project on GitHub with 2 branches:

```
upstream/Master
upstream/stable-v1
```

I forked the project so now in my private github account I have:

```
origin/Master
origin/stable-v1
```

I downloaded the project to my local mac using SSH so now in my mac I have:

```
Master  origin/Master
stable-v1 origin/stable-v1
```

To sync my local and origin of master i do:

```
git checkout master
git fetch --all
git reset --hard upstream/master
git push --force
```

But this sync only master. I want also to sync `stable-v1` the issue is that this branch needs to be synced from `upstream/stable-v1` and not from `master`!

When I do:

```
git checkout stable-v1
git pull --rebase
```

it tells me

```
Already up to date.
Current branch stable-v1 is up to date.
```

but this is not true I'm 1000+ commits behind.

I also tried to do that using Pycharm VCS options https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html#update-git-branch
but nothing works.

I think that it tries to sync my local copy from origin but what I'm trying to do is sync the local copy from upstream and then push it to origin.
Or is there a way to sync origin first and then pull it to local?
I'm very confused here.

Comment: When you do `git pull` it will take the default remote (`origin`). If `upstream` contains additional commits, then those are not automatically in `origin`.

Comment: I have to admit, I'm a bit confused how this question is different from your other question [How to sync git branch with remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66228371/how-to-sync-git-branch-with-remote-branch)? It is basically the same, but you have switched "merged" for "rebase". I think the previous answer still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way of working with remotes is to never use `pull`, but always use `fetch` followed by a `merge`/`rebase`. `pull` does the same behind the scenes, but I like to be able to inspect the history before that.

Fetch from all remotes, checkout your branch, rebase your branch:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout stable-v1
git rebase upstream/stable-v1
```

`rebase` generally has the form `--onto A B C` which takes all commits reachable from `C` but not from `B` (one might say "take all commits from B to C", but that is inaccurate) and copy it onto `A`.

Shorthands exist:

- `rebase --onto A A B` == `rebase A B`
- `rebase A current-branch` == `rebase A`

Comment: @sony are you sure this branch exists in the remote? Does `git branch -r` list this branch? (Or `git branch -r --list 'upstream*'`)

Comment: Great this solve my local copy being like upstream, but what about origin?

Comment: What do you mean with "what about origin"? To update refs on a remote, you need to push the refs.

Comment: The [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is a wonderful resource. [Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) should cover all common use cases.

Comment: How to push to a specific remote has been covered in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66228514/112968) to your earlier question.